# For loop to read file names

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python. I want to create a for loop that prints all the file names in my folder.

This is what I have :

```
import cf 
f = cf.read('/home/cd_files')
for i in f: 
  print f
```

The file names are string values. I am guessing what I failed to include in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: how deep do you want to print files. Like a folder can contain many other folders and then there are files. Do you want to print files recursively or just from inside one folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
for file in os.listdir('your/directory'):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to print all the files under the directory and sub directories.

```
   for root, dir, files in os.walk("/home/cd_files"):
        for file in files:
            print file
```

Comment: this will read all the files inside the folder, also in the subfolder itself.

Comment: yes i mentioned that in my comments, not sure why you down voted.

Comment: OP asked for single level not multiple level

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
files = os.listdir('your_directory/')
for file in files:
    print(file)
```